# jquery mobile rel="external" transition

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

For my phonegap app which i build with jquery mobile i use rel="external" if I want to go to another page, for example if I want to go from index.html to users.html..

I use this option because otherwise i can't use javascript functions in users.html.. for example it doesn't execute whats in the document.ready.. But.. if I use rel="external" then it will work..

The problem is, is that if I use rel="external" the transition(slide) won't work any more.. Does someone know why it is so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use pageinit instead of document.ready and rel="external". This is triggered after the page is initialised. There are other events you can use as well, depending on your needs such as pageshow or bagebeforeshow.

```
    $( '#aboutPage' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event){
  alert( 'This page was just enhanced by jQuery Mobile!' );
});
```

More on jQM events http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html

Here's what they say about document.ready:

> Important: Use $(document).bind('pageinit'), not $(document).ready()
>
> The first thing you learn in jQuery is to call code inside the
>   $(document).ready() function so everything will execute as soon as the
>   DOM is loaded. However, in jQuery Mobile, Ajax is used to load the
>   contents of each page into the DOM as you navigate, and the DOM ready
>   handler only executes for the first page. To execute code whenever a
>   new page is loaded and created, you can bind to the pageinit event.
>   This event is explained in detail at the bottom of this page.

Comment: pageinit, bind is the right way and next to that it is  also useful to put the function in an external js :)